How to get a Python Pandas script for cleaning an Excel file to include information past last column?
I have a Python script using libraries pandas and streamlit for inputting a messy excel file and outputting a clean one with no data shifts. I'm running into an issue where the script ignores data that is shifted too far over at the end of the Excel document. For example, for the last column in a file called ACTIVITY, there is data in the next two columns that do not have a header. The script should be reading in the below table and correcting it so that YES appears in the ACTIVITY column, but it's instead leaving the data in the blank columns.



ACTIVITY
(BLANK)
(BLANK)




(BLANK)
(BLANK)
YES


(BLANK)
YES
(BLANK)



Here is the function I am using to run through the Excel files:
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

def flattenList(nestedList):

    # check if list is empty
    if not(bool(nestedList)):
        return nestedList

    # to check instance of list is empty or not
    if isinstance(nestedList[0], list):

        # call function with sublist as argument
        return flattenList(*nestedList[:1]) + 
flattenList(nestedList[1:])

    # call function with sublist as argument
    return nestedList[:1] + flattenList(nestedList[1:])

@st.cache_data
def convert_df(df):
# IMPORTANT: Cache the conversion to prevent computation on rerun

return df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')


def alignCells(df):
    df = df.astype(str)
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].str.strip()

 #dataframe element's index location the dataframe element's value
    d = dict(zip(df.columns, range(len(df.columns))))
    s = df.rename(columns = d).stack()
    s = dict(s)

#list of problem cells that typically cause df to shift
    problems = ['LLC', 'LLP', 'Inc','Co.','LTD', "S.L."]
    locs = []
    for problem in problems:
        x = len(problem)

        for k,v in s.items():
            try:
                if v[0:x] == problem:
                    locs.append(k)
            except IndexError:
                pass

locs = flattenList(locs)
locs.sort()
locs
#concatenates incorrectly delimited string with the cell directly to 
its left
df = df.astype(str)
for x , y in locs:
    df.iloc[(x,(y-1))] = ((df.iloc[x,(y-1)]) + ', ' + df.iloc[x, 
(y)])

#get indices we need for realignment
rows = []
try:
    for i in range(0,len(locs)):
        c = locs[i][0]
        rows.append(c)

    xlocs = []
    for i in rows:
        if i not in xlocs:
            xlocs.append(i)

    ylocs = []
    for i in range(0,len(locs)):
        c = locs[i][1]
        ylocs.append(c)

#Excel index function
    for i in range(0,len(rows)):
        x = rows[i]

        if rows[i] == rows[i-5]:
            for j in range(1,len(df.columns)):
                if j == (len(df.columns)-1):
                    i += 1
                elif 0 <= j < ((ylocs[i])-5):
                    continue
                elif ((ylocs[i])-5) <= j:
                    df.iloc[x,j] = df.iloc[x,(j+1)]
        
        elif rows[i] == rows[i-4]:
            for j in range(1,len(df.columns)):
                if j == (len(df.columns)-1):
                    i += 1
                elif 0 <= j < ((ylocs[i])-4):
                    continue
                elif ((ylocs[i])-4) <= j:
                    df.iloc[x,j] = df.iloc[x,(j+1)]
        
        elif rows[i] == rows[i-3]:
            for j in range(1,len(df.columns)):
                if j == (len(df.columns)-1):
                    i += 1
                elif 0 <= j < ((ylocs[i])-3):
                    continue
                elif ((ylocs[i])-3) <= j:
                    df.iloc[x,j] = df.iloc[x,(j+1)]

        elif rows[i] == rows[i-2]:
            for j in range(1,len(df.columns)):
                if j == (len(df.columns)-1):
                    i += 1
                elif 0 <= j < ((ylocs[i])-2):
                    continue
                elif ((ylocs[i])-2) <= j:
                    df.iloc[x,j] = df.iloc[x,(j+1)]
        elif rows[i] == rows[i-1]:
            for j in range(1,len(df.columns)):
                if j == (len(df.columns)-1):
                    i += 1
                elif 0 <= j < ((ylocs[i])-1):
                    continue
                elif ((ylocs[i])-1) <= j:
                    df.iloc[x,j] = df.iloc[x,(j+1)]
        else:
            for j in range(1,len(df.columns)):
                if j == (len(df.columns)-1):
                    i += 1
                elif 0 <= j < ylocs[i]:
                    continue
                elif ylocs[i] <= j:
                    df.iloc[x,j] = df.iloc[x,(j+1)]
except IndexError:
    pass


I believe what would need to be fixed is to expand the length of the columns as defined in the dataframe, or have the function read past the end of the dataframe to reach any data that exists beyond its definition and pull it back to where the actual last column is in the dataframe.
Thank you in advance to anyone who has taken the time to read this and provide feedback.

locs appears undefined in the provided portion of the code? Also it looks like a larger part of the excel file (or is it already in a dataframe?) would be needed. See [ask] and [mre] for good tips to write a question we can answer.
